# How to get program to not go with first option

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a program that retrieves weather information from the closest location to my own. I then noticed after what seemed to be success is that the program would go with the first option of weather data available available which is located about 6,373 kilometers away. Does anyone have a suggestion? Note: for privacy reasons, I replaced my coordinates with x. you can insert your own coordinates and the program should work. I am also rather new at python so please try to not over complicate your answers.

```py
from requests import get
import json
from pprint import pprint
from haversine import haversine

stations = 'https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getallstations'
weather = 'https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/raspberrypi/weatherstation/getlatestmeasurements/'

my_lat = x
my_lon = x

all_stations = get(stations).json()['items']

def find_closest():
    smallest = 20036
    for station in all_stations:
        station_lon = station['weather_stn_long']
        station_lat = station['weather_stn_lat']
        distance = haversine(my_lon, my_lat, station_lon, station_lat)
        if distance < smallest:
            smallest = distance
            closest_station = station['weather_stn_id']
            print(distance)
        return closest_station

closest_stn = find_closest()
weather = weather + str(closest_stn)

my_weather = get(weather).json()['items']
pprint(my_weather)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return closest_station` should not be in the loop. That causes the function to return on the first iteration, rather than after you go through all the stations.

That line should have the same indentation as the `for` statement so it's executed after the loop is done.